# Wordpress "Media Librery" no carga

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Recientemente he creado un template desde cero en WP. Cuando incluyo estas lineas de codigo en el functions.php en referencia a una base de datos creada al efecto no carga la libreria de medios.

```
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/database.php';

require get_template_directory() . '/inc/reservas.php';

require get_template_directory() . '/inc/opciones.php';
```

Curiosamente cuando comento la primera "//". Vuelven a cargar.

Tengo activado el DEBUG.LOG pero no me da ningún error de php.
Un alma caritativa que me ayude. ;-)
Muchas gracias.

Comment: O sea ¿cuando comentas esto funciona: `require get_template_directory() . '/inc/database.php';`? Si es así, significa que algo anormal ocurre en el archivo `database.php` o bien el mismo no existe en esa ruta. ¿Por qué no revisas ese archivo no sea que esté interfiriendo en algo o que tenga algún error? Sería bueno que revises también el `error_log` allí podrás encontrar más informaciones de error. ¿Cómo tienes activado el `DEBUG`?, es raro que no muestre nada.

Comment: Muchas Gracias. A. Cedano. He conseguido arreglarlo. El Debug lo tengo activado y el Log tb. Y no me daba ningun error. Muy raro. Eran unas lineas de codigo que añadí. /*Asi*/. Y despues de la etiqueta <?php  ?> No entiendo porque. Suelo añadir comentarios para acordarme de las cosas cuando estoy desarrollando.

Comment: Si lo tenías así: `<?php ?>/*Comentario*/` seguro seguro que tenías un error, ya que `?>` cierra el bloque de código PHP.

Comment: Si era justo eso! Gracias